# How to encrypt external usb hard drive?

Tags: security, external-hard-drive, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to encrypt data on an external hard drive?](https://superuser.com/questions/96898/how-to-encrypt-data-on-an-external-hard-drive)

This is my problem, I'm a student and I live with two roommates. When I go to school, I carry my external HDD with me for protection, because I'm scared that they will copy everything from the HDD when I'm not around to see it. So I googled and saw that encryption is the only way to secure with password, but I'm scared to try why I think that it will delete all my data. The external hard drive is [Apacer AC202 SATA External Hard Drive](http://emea.apacer.com/en/products/AC202_SATA_External_Hard_Drive_specs.htm). With it comes a backup software that makes invisible partition so no one can see it, but again, I'm scared to try. So please help me to understand encryption more clearly, step by step (it will be more helpful with pictures or video). Please share other options for securing the HDD to.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any particular OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

encyption is ownly a problem if you forget your password[generally]
try turecypt-http://www.truecrypt.org/
It free, opensource and comes with more information than i can provide.Follow the instructions and you should find it as simple as logon.
edit-more info,related linksThese sites will help your understanding of encyption.
http://www.governmentsecurity.org/EncryptionInformationandArticles.php
http://www.governmentsecurity.org/forum/index.php?showforum=34

Comment: sorry meiko i had my answer half written your -vote up and answer-if?

Answer (score 2):

I usually use this program, so far i like it :D
It provides a good tutorial for the usage you are looking for :)

http://www.truecrypt.org/